# IONIC use another file directory for images located in a custom component

Tags: ionic-framework, background-image, custom-component

I want to use in a custom component a background image, but I can't find how to use it from the scss file.

I think there must be a way to define another directory for my images. I don't want to mess up files that correspond to this specific component sending them to 'www' directory.

Is there a way?

I give you an example of what i want:

Let's say I have a component defined in 'src/app/shared/components/my-custom-component'. Inside this directory I have a '/image' directory with all the images I want to use in this component. Then, in the 'my-custom-component.scss' I want to use this images using backgroun-image...

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Put all images in `src/assets`

Comment: It seems to be the only way...

Comment: You can access to images folder in scss with `background-image: url('assets/...')`